# How to use mybatis to select image that store in mysql database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mybatis

I have a class

```
public class Images{ 
    private int id;
    private byte[] img;
    private String name;
}
```

table in database T_image( id tinyint, logo_img mediumblob, name varchar)

I have a dao interface

```
public interface ImgDAO{
  public List<byte[]> selectAllImg();
}
```

I want to write the sqlmapper for this in xml mapper of mybatis

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232703/fetching-a-longblob-as-a-byte-array-using-mybatis

Comment: i want to use : select logo_img from T_image;

Answer (score 1):

Use resultMap like this

```
<resultMap class="Images" id="imageResultMap">
       <result column="logo_img" property="img" jdbcType="BLOB"/>
  </resultMap>

  <select id="selectAllImg" resultMap="imageResultMap">
        select logo_img from T_image
  </select>
```

Comment: cannot use property class but used type instead of class. if I wand  select logo_img from T_image; what shold the type be??

Comment: I create the setter and getter already but it said there is no setter for the logo_img property .