# What is the jdbc type and java type for LONG RAW column?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, long-integer

I am facing a strange issue. I have a table `file_data`. It has a column called `filedata` and the data type is `long raw`. In this column a hexadecimal representation of an excel file gets stored like `D01A01....`. Now I have a procedure called 'PROC_STORE_DATA'. I am calling this procedure from my java class and trying to insert an excel spreadsheet content inside that table column.

In my Java class, I am getting the file content like this:

```
byte[] bytes = fileData.getBytes();
StringBuffer hexSt = new StringBuffer();
for(byte b : bytes){
    hextSt.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}
```

I  have a hashmap called procData where in I push this `hexSt` variable.

```
procData.put('fileData',hextSt.toString().toUpperCase());
```

Then, I call my update method to update the table via my procedure:

```
myUpdateDao().update(PROC_STORE_DATA,procData);
```

In mybatis.xml, this is how I have defined the column to be updated in the parameter map:

```xml
<parameterMap>
    <parameter property="updatefileData" javatype="java.lang.String" jdbcType="LONGVARCHAR">
</parameterMap>
```

But after running this, I get this error: `wrong number or types of arguments in the procedure call - PLS-00306 and ORA-06550`.

I have spent 2 days and yet I don't understand where the issue is. The issue may be with javaType and jdbcType, but I am not sure what should I give as javaType and jdbcType here for a column with data type `LONG RAW` .

After using `longvarbinary` and `byte[]` as mentioned in the answer by ewramner,
I am getting a class cast exception: `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to `[L java.lang.Byte`

Comment: The data type mappings [are in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/accessing-and-manipulating-Oracle-data.html#GUID-231E827F-77EE-4648-B0C4-98651F9CE03F). LONG and LOG RAW are different data types, one is character, the other binary.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks Alex

Comment: Don't convert the bytes to a hex string, try to insert the raw byte values

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Tried that ... now I get another class cast exception , which says [B cannot be cast to [L java.lang.Byte

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `byte[]` and `LONGVARBINARY`.

Comment: When I try this out,  I am getting a class cast exception: `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to `[L java.lang.Byte` . Any ideas ?

Comment: I haven't used ibatis, but try procData.put("fileData", bytes). You want to save the raw bytes from the file.

Comment: I need to save the byes from the file , but they have to be in hexadecimal . The column contains hexadecimal data as I have posted in the question .

Comment: Are you sure? I think the column contains raw bytes (hence the column type RAW) that are displayed in hexadecimal. I still think you should save the bytes without coding them in hex.

Comment: Tried that ... now I get another class cast exception , which says  `[B`  cannot  be cast to `[L java.lang.Byte` . Not sure what else to do here .

Comment: It seems mybatis is trying to use Byte[] rather than byte[]. How is your configuration looking right now?

Comment: According to another post the Java type should be "_byte[]".

Comment: Let me check the configuration

Comment: It seems mybatis accepts only Byte object array . _byte[] gives PL/SQL: numeric or value error . May be I need to write customHandlerCallback for this.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232703/fetching-a-longblob-as-a-byte-array-using-mybatis? Perhaps you can use a wrapper class?

Comment: Are you sure that: "_byte[] gives PL/SQL: numeric or value error" isn't a CORRECT work of your code? I mean that you can get this error just because you're passing a byte array too large for a PL-SQL proc parameter. PL-SQL engine only supports arrays of 32760 bytes long for a LONG RAW.

Answer (score 1):

As per Hibernate Oracle's dialect it will be `LONGVARBINARY`. See `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect`:

```
registerColumnType( Types.LONGVARBINARY, "long raw" );
```